# RoleBinding not granting permissions

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have the following `RoleBinding` (it was deployed by Helm:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: environment-namespaces
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: namespace-metadata
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-23T17:16:50Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: SA-DevK8s-admin
  namespace: dev-my-product-name-here
  resourceVersion: "29221536"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/dev-my-product-name-here/rolebindings/SA-DevK8s-admin
  uid: 4818d6ed-9320-408c-82c3-51e627d9f375
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: SA-DevK8s@mydomain.com
```

When I login to the cluster as `SA-DevK8s@mydomain.com` and run `kubectl get pods -n dev-my-product-name-here` it get the following error:

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "sa-devk8s@mydomain.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "dev-my-product-name-here"

**Shouldn't a user who has the ClusterRole of admin in a namespace be able to list the pods for that namespace?**

Answer (score 1):

**Case Matters!!!!**

Once I changed the user to be `sa-devk8s@mydomain.com` (instead of `SA-DevK8s@mydomain.com`), it all started working correctly!